# Cypress custom command in TS is not recognized during tests ('TypeError: cy.a is not a function')

Tags: typescript, cypress

I have a very simple Cypress test specification which is the following:

```
// integration/connection.ts

describe("First page displayed", function() {
    before(() => {
        cy.visit("/")
    })

    it("Is an error page when no token is given", function() {
        cy.getByDataAttribute("error-page")
    )}
})
```

Now the `getByDataAttribute` is a custom command defined like so:

```
// support/commands.ts

declare namespace Cypress {
  interface Chainable<Subject> {
    getByDataAttribute: typeof getByDataAttribute
  }
}

/**
 * Get a DOM element by targeting its data-cy attribute value
 * @param data_target data-cy attribute value to target
 */
function getByDataAttribute(data_target: string) {
  return cy.get("[data-cy=" + data_target + "]")
}

Cypress.Commands.add("getByDataAttribute", getByDataAttribute)
```

As you can see, everything is written in TypeScript and compiles fine (I even get IntelliSense for my custom command.) I also have my `support/index.ts` which only imports the commands:

```
import './commands'
```

I can't figure out what goes wrong but when running the test, Cypress throws the following error:

> TypeError: cy.getByDataAttribute is not a function

My custom command previously worked, and it's when I tried adding IntelliSense that I started having problems. Now even if I revert back to vanilla JS, the command is not recognized. I tried a lot of tweaks in the configuration and can't remember everything I tried but I think now everything is in order and should work. But it obviously doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

For IntelliSense we use following but in JS:

```
///<reference types="cypress"/>
```

Comment: TypeScript has no problem picking up the function and IntelliSense is also providing documentation and autocompletion about it. The problem really lies with Cypress which doesn't register the function.

Answer (score 0):

1) Is your example stripped down from your actual custom command by chance?  And imports anything?

I ran into this issue following some guide online, but my custom command used an object imported from another module.  In this case you have to use the global namespace declaration.  Either way, it's worth it a try to see if the global namespace works for you

2) You've added your command to the `Chainable<Subject>` interface, that is used for chaining off something, like `cy.get("#something").myCommand()` but your command is used directly off of `cy`, so it should be on the `Chainable` interface.

```
// support/commands.ts
import { someObject } from "someModule";

declare global { // < SEE HERE FOR 1)
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable { // < SEE HERE FOR 2)
      getByDataAttribute: typeof getByDataAttribute
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Get a DOM element by targeting its data-cy attribute value
 * @param data_target data-cy attribute value to target
 */
function getByDataAttribute(data_target: string) {
  // do something with someObject here
  return cy.get("[data-cy=" + data_target + "]")
}

Cypress.Commands.add("getByDataAttribute", getByDataAttribute)


export {}; // < Don't forget this!
```

See here for more info:

https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1065#issuecomment-410324355

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did not strip it down, it's only a shortcut because we only use data attribute to focus elements from Cypress. I will try your advice as soon as I can